# Attaching a debugger to swagger node

Tags: swagger-node-express, swagger-node, swagger-node-runner

I have a node swagger project using:

```
"swagger-node-runner": "0.7.3",
```

I'm using webstorm and I'm trying to attached a debugger to my source code. 
Controller code, but I cannot. Can someone please help ?
I'm tried 30 different things and I can't get it work.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I've been trying for hours and can't debug the swagger controllers, it basically makes developing for this a pain.

Comment: I think I did, I'm not sure what I changed. I can debug my handlers and all. What have you tried?

Comment: I ended up using Visual Studio Code, never did get it working in WebStorm